# Radial slider UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, slider

I would like to create a radial slider. this is the code i wrote but i can't understand where i am wrong.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="GridBase" Width="207" Height="207">
        <Grid Height="207" Width="207" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path Stroke="#FF34A1ED" StrokeThickness="7" x:Name="arcPath" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="3.5" TranslateY="3.5"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure x:Name="myArcStart" StartPoint="7.612,61.6317">
                            <ArcSegment x:Name="myArc" IsLargeArc="true" Point="192.388,61.6317" Size="100,100"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="CanvasVolume" Width="207" Height="207" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="CompositePoint" Rotation="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse x:Name="VolumePoint" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#9923678A" PointerPressed="VolumePoint_PointerPressed" Canvas.Top="{x:Bind TopPosition, Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.Left="{x:Bind LeftPosition, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double topPosition = 55.2317;
    public double TopPosition
    {
        get => topPosition;
        set
        {
            topPosition = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TopPosition)));
        }
    }

    private double leftPosition = 1.112;
    public double LeftPosition
    {
        get => leftPosition;
        set
        {
            leftPosition = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LeftPosition)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void VolumePoint_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point puntopressd = e.GetCurrentPoint(CanvasVolume).Position;

        PointerEventHandler moved = null;
        moved = (s, args) =>
        {
            CanvasVolume.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
            Point puntomoved = e.GetCurrentPoint(CanvasVolume).Position;

            double puntoX = puntomoved.X;
            double puntoY = puntomoved.Y;
            double raggio = 100;

            if (puntoX < 100 && puntoY < 100)
            {
                double C1 = raggio - puntoY;
                double C2 = Math.Sqrt((raggio * raggio) - (C1 * C1));

                double RadBeta = ((C1 * C1) + (raggio * raggio) - (C2 * C2)) / (2 * C1 * raggio);
                double Beta = Math.Acos(RadBeta);

                double coorX = raggio * (1 - Math.Sin(Beta));

                TopPosition = puntoY - 6;
                LeftPosition = coorX - 6;
            }
            else if (puntoX < 100 && puntoY > 100)
            {
                double C1 = puntoY - raggio;
                double C2 = Math.Sqrt((raggio * raggio) - (C1 * C1));

                double RadBeta = ((raggio * raggio) + (C1 * C1) - (C2 * C2)) / (2 * C1 * raggio);
                double Beta = Math.Acos(RadBeta);

                double coorX = raggio * (1 - Math.Sin(Beta));

                TopPosition = puntoY - 6;
                LeftPosition = coorX - 6;
            }
            else if (puntoX > 100 && puntoY > 100)
            {
                double C1 = puntoY - raggio;
                double C2 = Math.Sqrt((raggio * raggio) - (C1 * C1));

                double RadBeta = ((raggio * raggio) + (C1 * C1) - (C2 * C2)) / (2 * C1 * raggio);
                double Beta = Math.Acos(RadBeta);

                double coorX = raggio + C2;

                TopPosition = puntoY - 6;
                LeftPosition = coorX - 6;
            }
            else if (puntoX > 100 && puntoY < 100)
            {
                double C1 = raggio - puntoY;
                double C2 = Math.Sqrt((raggio * raggio) - (C1 * C1));

                double RadBeta = ((C1 * C1) + (raggio * raggio) - (C2 * C2)) / (2 * C1 * raggio);
                double Beta = Math.Acos(RadBeta);

                double coorX = raggio + C2;

                TopPosition = puntoY - 6;
                LeftPosition = coorX - 6;
            }

        };

        PointerEventHandler released = null;
        released = (s, args) =>
        {
            Point puntoreleas = e.GetCurrentPoint(CanvasVolume).Position;

            CanvasVolume.PointerMoved -= moved;
            CanvasVolume.PointerReleased -= released;
        };
        CanvasVolume.PointerMoved += moved;
        CanvasVolume.PointerReleased += released;
    }
}
```

The ellipse moves from one side to the other and in the points of 0 and 180 degrees it disappears how can I solve? I think the problem is in the conditions posed but I am not sure.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > The ellipse moves from one side to the other and in the points of 0 and 180 degrees it disappears.

In `puntoX > 100 and puntoY > 100`, sometimes the function `Math.Sqrt((raggio * raggio) - (C1 * C1))` will return **NaN**. When the value of C1 property is greater than raggio,  so the squared value is negative, then it returns NaN and the ellipse disappears. You can solve this issue from this point.

In addition, I have another simple workaround that using some characteristics of the circle to deal with it can make the ellipse moves well. You can try the following code snippet.

```
moved = (s, args) =>
{
    CanvasVolume.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
    Point puntomoved = e.GetCurrentPoint(CanvasVolume).Position;

    double puntoX = puntomoved.X;
    double puntoY = puntomoved.Y;
    double raggio = 100;

    double halfWidth = CanvasVolume.ActualHeight / 2;
    double slashLength = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(puntoY - halfWidth) * Math.Abs(puntoY - halfWidth) + (Math.Abs(halfWidth - puntoX) * Math.Abs(halfWidth - puntoX))));

    LeftPosition = CanvasVolume.ActualHeight / 2 + ((puntoX - halfWidth) * raggio / slashLength) - VolumePoint.Width/2;
    TopPosition = puntoY - ((puntoY - halfWidth) * (slashLength - raggio) / slashLength) - VolumePoint.Width / 2;

};

PointerEventHandler released = null;
released = (s, args) =>
{
    Point puntoreleas = e.GetCurrentPoint(CanvasVolume).Position;

    CanvasVolume.PointerMoved -= moved;
    CanvasVolume.PointerReleased -= released;
};
CanvasVolume.PointerMoved += moved;
CanvasVolume.PointerReleased += released;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I wanted to ask one last thing. How can I calculate the angle given the coordinates found?

Comment: You can use [Math.Asin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.asin?view=netframework-4.8) method to get the angle. First getting the chord length between two points and using Asin method to get the angle.